# Cannot reattach to a screen session after SSH connection was dropped

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

I have previously reattached to a long-running screen session with `screen -dr control`. However, sometimes this command will not reattach to the screen and instead hang forever (10+ minutes after which I aborted). This only happens when the SSH connection is dropped unexpectedly and not when the screen is properly detached with `Ctrl-A d`. Other switches, such as `screen -x` or `screen -D -RR` also do not work.

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/98535/cant-get-detached-screen-to-resume) suggests to kill the PTY that holds the screen session which will cause screen to complete its disconnect. However, it simply kills the shell from which `screen -dr control` was called.

For example:

```
$ ps -ef | grep control | grep -v grep
nomad     7387  7109  0 13:05 pts/50   00:00:00 screen -dr control
nomad    15299     1  0 Nov27 ?        00:13:47 SCREEN -S control

$ ps -ef | grep bash | grep 'pts/50'
nomad     7109  7108  0 12:49 pts/50   00:00:00 -bash
```

The linked post suggest to kill the `bash` process with PID 7109. This will also kill the `screen -dr control` process with PID 7387. Afterwards, I still cannot connect to the screen.

The process `SCREEN -S control` which started the screen session has `init` as its parent which I obviously cannot kill.

Is there a way to reattach to the hung screen session?

Update: This happens on CentOS 6.4 using kernel 2.6.32-358.6.1.el6.x86_64. The shells are all bash version 4.1.2(1)-release.

Comment: What does `screen -ls`says in those "hanging" cases ? `screen -d -r <session>`means "detach and recover" so not having detached it first-hand shouldn't matter. (And for doing it often, it doesn't...)

Comment: Try running lsof on the screen processes, see if there is something "stuck."  Screen uses a unix socket to communicate between processes, likely something has kept it open.  Also make sure that the socket hasn't gotten deleted or its ownership changed or something.  In general you should also include what OS and version you are using, although I don't have anything particular in mind that would be os-dependent this time around.

Comment: Are you ssh'ing via another hop, e.g. using netcat as a proxy command? In this case I have had the problem where the ssh connection to the first box drops, but the netcat proxy command keeps a 'second' ssh connection open. the -d should work however.

Comment: Jens, your advice did the trick. I did indeed proxy through netcat and killing it on the intermediate host enabled me to reattach to the screen.

Comment: Why would you want to kill the hung screen command's parent process? You want to kill the attaching screen command itself. #7387 in your case.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs Ultimately, I want to reattach to the screen session.  Simply killing PID 7387 will not let me reattach to PID 15299.

Comment: Right, current `screen` still thinks you're attached after you kill the client, which arguably is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Jens Timmerman, the ultimate reason for this strange behavior was that I was connecting to the remote server using SSH ProxyCommand and `ncat`. After killing the `ncat` on the intermediate machine, I am able to reattach to the screen session.

Answer (score 5):

I think you should try

```
screen -DR
```

next time too - the angry (uppercase) invocation should force it to disconnect that other session being held by your intermediate netcat hop.

Comment: I tried this, it does not work. Killing the netcat proxy does the trick.

Comment: Strange. It should. What does happen instead?

Comment: All further invocations of screen (-dr, -x, -DR) hang forever. Once I've killed the netcat proxy, these invocations work again.

Answer (score -2):

If this is a frequent issue you could also consider using mosh as an ssh replacement:

http://mosh.mit.edu